# When debugging, how do you estimate if you should rewrite or keep looking?

Tags: debugging

You have all met this scenario. I am using a new algorithm for the first time, and I am sitting at my computer trying to find out if it is some syntax problem or if I have misunderstood the algorithm. In a scenario like this, I would sooner rewrite the program than spend time staring at the screen. But this raises the general question, that I am curious to hear from programmers more experienced than myself:

How do you judge when it is the right time to rewrite, or should you continue sitting there staring at your code looking for the bug?

Are there any useful heuristics that professional programmers use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't sound right to me at all. As long as you don't understand the (required) **algorithm** you should not write code. That's called trial and error and is a pretty sure way to end up with poor and buggy code. Think before you act.

As food for thought a bit provocative statement:

> Writing code is the last thing to do. Being a coder might sound like
>   you should be typing a lot but in fact if I count how many characters
>   an average programmer commits each day and ask some secretary to type
>   the same amount he/she would be done in under 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very difficult question and really depends on your case.

Typically, there are two cases :

- the algorithm is simple and you will find the bug fast. A rewrite is generally not necessary unless you want to optimize it.
- the algorithm is really complex : it's difficult to find the bug. But It can be difficult to rewrite because you can miss some subtile features of the algorithm. The risk is to have a new algorithm but with new bugs !

I don't think there is a clean answer to that problem. I would say that it's better to find the bug than rewriting all. Rewriting is necessary when you need to optimize or clean the code (not because you don't find a bug).

That's my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

You should never rewrite something that has already gone through testing more than once.. the theory being that if you went through it at least once, you've already ironed out bugs. Trying to recreate the end-result of those resolved bugs is very difficult. Joel has a very good article on this, and I tend to agree, even though I have been in the position you are, and my inclination was to just throw it away and rewrite it..

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html